# Вызовом метода контроллера в представлении

Tags: вёрстка, ruby-on-rails

Добрый день. Я пытаюсь сделать блок с отзывами на главной странице сайта, для чего с помощью scaffold создал базу данных в которой есть поля comment и author куда сохраняются отзывы, контроллер, представление и модель. При попытке поместить отзывы на главную страницу способом:

```
    <section class="one-half column-last">
        <h2>Отзывы <span class="more">&ndash; <a href="#">Просмотреть все отзывы &raquo;</a></span></h2> 

        <ul class="testimonial-carousel">
            <li>
                <blockquote class="speech-bubble">
                    <% @testimonials.each do |testimonial| %>
                        <div class="quote-content">
                            <p><%= testimonial.comment %></p>
                            <span class="quote-arrow"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="quote-meta">
                            <%= testimonial.author%>
                        </div>
                    <% end %>
                </blockquote>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
```

я получаю ошибку undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass.

Если изменить вызов метода контроллера на

```
<% Testimonial.all.each do |testimonial| %>
```

отзывы добавляются в карусель, но все сразу одновременно, из за чего не работает прокрутка.

В контроллере Testimonial:

```
class TestimonialsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @testimonials = Testimonial.all
  end
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с вызовом метода контроллера, и правильной его работой в представлении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass.
```

Означает, что @testimonials не инициализирована в контроллере. Нужно добавить в контроллере в метод, который рисует главную страницу, код для выборки всех отзывов:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @testimonials = Testimonial.all
  end
end
```

Либо для вывода последних десяти отзывов:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @testimonials = Testimonial.order(:created_at).last(10)
  end
end
```

Тогда во вьюшке можно будет использовать конструкцию

```
<section class="one-half column-last">
  <h2>Отзывы <span class="more">&ndash; <a href="#">Просмотреть все отзывы &raquo;</a></span></h2> 

    <ul class="testimonial-carousel">
      <blockquote class="speech-bubble">
        <% @testimonials.each do |testimonial| %>
          <li>
            <div class="quote-content">
              <p><%= testimonial.comment %></p>
              <span class="quote-arrow"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="quote-meta">
              <%= testimonial.author%>
            </div>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </blockquote>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Спасибо, на главной заработало, но как и при
    <% Testimonial.all.each do |testimonial| %> (тут я так понимаю обращение к другому контроллеру напрямую из представления?) они все выводятся одновременно, я понимаю, что это вопрос уже больше по верстке, но если вы знаете, я попросил бы помочь еще и в этом.

Comment: Я выше привел два примера -- первый для вывода всех, второй для N последних.

Comment: По поводу верстки -- я обновил ответ, надо обратить внимание, где теперь находится контейнер li. Я перенес его внутрь цикла, теперь он будет отрисован столько раз, сколько отзывов будет в переменной  @testimonials